# How to change the url as specified in .htaccess file

Tags: php, url

I have wrote code in .htaccess file to change the standard URL to friendly URL.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But unfortunately, I don't know how can I adjust the php code to compatible with the code that in .htaccess file

The following is just a simple code, because I don't know how can I do that.

```
$url = $_GET[0]; // I don't know how to get the unknown parameters

if(file_exists("controllers/". $url . ".php")){
    require_once ("controllers/". $url . ".php");
    if(class_exists($url)){
        $controller = new $url;
    }else{
        echo "Class deos not exists.";
    }

}else{
    echo "File deos not exists.";
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @5ervant: I want to write a php code to make the url compatible with this code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`.

Comment: Debugging with `print_r($_GET);` and `print_r($_SERVER);`. Those bland copynpaste RewriteRules could just be replaced with `FallBackResource`, btw.

Comment: @mario: Sorry, but I don't understand you, could you clarify more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the `/$1` part of the URL.

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] === "/main") {
    echo "Main Page";
} elseif ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] === "/sub") {
    echo "Sub Page";
} else {
    echo "File does not exists.";
}
```

> What about if I change this the code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
>   [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` . I have been removed
>   `?`.

Then you can use the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` for that..

```
$pathInfo = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

if ($pathInfo === "/main") {
    echo "Main Page";
} elseif ($pathInfo === "/sub") {
    echo "Sub Page";
} else {
    echo "File does not exists.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but What about if I change this the code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` . I have been removed `?`. I think must use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. as Fuser97381 said ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.